# Mysql query issue with if statements in select

Tags: mysql

Trying to get this query to work. I'm having issues with brackets I think.

```
SELECT (fielda - fieldb - ( 
 IF ((cola <= 5), 
     1, 
     IF ((cola >= 6 AND cola <= 12), 
         2, 
         IF ((cola >= 13 AND cola <= 20), 
             3, 
             IF ((cola >= 21 AND cola <= 28), 4)
             )
         )
    ) )) 
AS result FROM the table r WHERE r.fieldx = 3148 AND cola <= 18 ORDER BY result LIMIT 1
```

Mysql returns:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')))) ) AS result FROM

Comment: added some indentation that makes counting the brackets easier; looks ok so far. Can you post the error message?

Comment: you might try leaving away the outside brackets, there's at least no reason to have them and maybe they even create problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `IF` does not have an else argument. While one might expect MySQL to understand this anyhow, it doesn't appear to be valid syntax according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess (and going by the information you've provided) I would say the last `IF()` is missing an else condition which is making the math function fail.

```
IF ((cola >= 21 AND cola <= 28), 4, ???)
```

Populate the question marks with an "all else fails"/"default" value and you should be safe. However, I *believe* mysql (assuming it's a non-nullable field) will use the default value for the type/column if you specify `NULL` as the else condition (but I may be wrong).